# R + ggplot. Draw children data in same plot as parent data

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization

Having Titanic dataset I draw histograms of age/sex against the passenger class.

`str(titanic)` gives the following data

```
> 'data.frame': 714 obs. of  4 variables:  
$ Survived: int  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...  
$ Pclass  : int  3 1 3 1 3 1 3 3 2 3 ...  
$ Sex     : chr "male" "female" "female" "female" ...  
$ Age     : num  22 38 26 35 35 54 2 27 14 4 ...
```

First, I made a plot of proportion of male/female against the travel classes.

It has been done by

```
ggplot(data = titanic, aes(x = factor(Age), fill = factor(Sex))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Pclass) + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(20,40,60)) + 
  ylab("Frequency") + xlab("Age") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name  = "Sex")
```

[image]

Now I want to use the **same** graph, but add additional information -> proportion of survivals for all categories.
For example, what is the proportion of survival women age 20-30 who traveled the first class.

I would like to see it in the same bars, i.e split each column into two parts(survived/not survived).

Can I do it with ggplot? And if yes, how?

Comment: Can you provide code to go from the 4d `Titanic` array to your `titanic` df?

Comment: You probably want to `fill` by survival and `facet_grid(Sex~P.class)`.

Comment: Do you achieve your goal by using `facet_grid(. ~ Pclass + Survived)` ?

Comment: Sorry for the long reply.
I used the titanic df from one of the datacamp classes. 

I'm quite happy with Mark Peterson answer, so I have no more questions from my side.

Answer (score 1):

Using the builtin Titanic data set, I can show you roughly what @Axeman suggested in the comments. Note that it only has two categories for age (Child/Adult) so you would need to decide how to bin for your data.

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(Titanic)
       , aes(y = Freq
             , x = Age
             , fill = Survived)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ Class)
```

[image]

Importantly, I am not sure that you are gaining anything by showing the frequencies in the way you currently are, as they do not appear to be showing anything meaningfully different than the counts would. If, instead, you wanted to show the proportion within each group that survived, you may be better off calculating those percentages first, then passing them to `ggplot`. Here is an example of that using `dplyr`. Again, your age bins can be whatever you want, but note that the narrower the bins, the more noisy the data will be.

```
as.data.frame(Titanic) %>%
  group_by(Class, Sex, Age) %>%
  mutate(Proportion = Freq/ sum(Freq)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Proportion
             , x = Age
             , fill = Survived)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ Class)
```

[image]